# Ansible: copy from one dir to another (clean copy)

Tags: ansible

I want to perform a clean copy from dirA to dirB. If there are contents in dirB but not in dirA, I want them to be deleted. I have following ansible job but it doesn't seem to delete old files present in dirB (but not in dirA).

```
- name: Clean copy from dirA to dirB
  synchronize:
    src: dirA
    dest: dirB
    delete: yes
    recursive: yes
    dirs: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/synchronize_module.html

Answer (score 0):

i think the `dirs` and `recursive` directives might be colliding. from the docs here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html

```
dirs (default: no) Transfer directories without recursing.
recursive: Recurse into directories. This parameter defaults to the value of the archive option.
```